# Is it possible to use Google Wallet to send money between users of a third party Android application?

Tags: android, android-pay

I am developing an Android application.  I would like for my users to be able to send money to one another inside my app.  Is this at all possible using Google Wallet?  If not, what are some other services or ways to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, no (IINM, policies will also prevent such). `Google Wallet` (already) has it's own send money feature on mobile (and is integrated with GMAIL on desktop "attach money")

[Bank apps](https://www.wellsfargo.com/jump/online-banking/send-to-anyone), [`Square Cash`](https://square.com/cash) and such are some that also do this.